# Resuming neural network training after a certain epoch in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am training a neural network with a constant learning rate and epoch = 45. I observed that the accuracy is highest at epoch no 35 and then it wiggles around and decreases. I think I need to reduce the learning rate at epoch 35. Is there any chance that I can train the model again from epoch no 35 after the completion of all the epochs? My code is shown below-

```
model_nn = keras.Sequential()
model_nn.add(Dense(352, input_dim=28, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(384, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(288, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(448, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(320, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


auc_score = tf.keras.metrics.AUC()

model_nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                 optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), 
                                                 metrics=['accuracy',auc_score])

history = model_nn.fit(X_train1, y_train1,
                       validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
                       epochs=45, 
                       batch_size=250, 
                       verbose=1)

_, accuracy = model_nn.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
# Saving model weights
model_nn.save('mymodel.h5')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two useful things:

1. Use the [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) callback with the `save_best_only=True` parameter. It only saves when the model is considered the "best" and the latest best model according to the quantity monitored will not be overwritten.
2. Use the [ReduceLROnPlateau](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) and [EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) callbacks. `ReduceLROnPlateau` will reduce learning rate when the metric has stops improving for the validation subset. `EarlyStopping` will stop training when a monitored metric has stopped improving at all.

In simple words, `ReduceLROnPlateau` helps us find the global minimum, `EarlyStopping` takes care of the number of epochs, and `ModelCheckpoint` will save the best model.

The code might look like this:

```
early_stoping = EarlyStopping(patience=5, min_delta=0.0001)
reduce_lr_loss = ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=2, verbose=1, min_delta=0.0001, factor=0.65)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(save_best_only=True)

history = model_nn.fit(X_train1, y_train1,
                       validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
                       epochs=100, 
                       batch_size=250, 
                       verbose=1,
                       callbacks=[early_stoping, reduce_lr_loss, model_checkpoint])
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to reduce the learning rate manually after a certain epoch and resume the new training again?